# Чем хорош паттерн Arrange, Act, Assert и стоит ли им пользоваться всегда?

Tags: java, юнит-тесты, junit

Я вижу в этом паттерне только один плюс: он улучшает читаемость. 
А минусов больше:

*Во-первых,* это далеко не всегда улучшает читаемость. Вот простой тест:

```
@Test
public void testAdditionAndSize() {
    int expectedSize = 3;
    int actualSize = list.size();
    assertEquals(expectedSize, actualSize);
}
```

Вместо этого я мог бы написать так:

```
@Test
public void testAdditionAndSize() {
    assertEquals(3, list.size());
}
```

Разве пострадала читаемость?

*Во-вторых*, что делать вот с таким тестом?

```
@Test
public void testIsEmpty() {
    assertTrue(!list.isEmpty());
}
```

Неужели тоже создавать 2 булевы переменные, а потом сравнивать их?

```
@Test
public void testIsEmpty() {
    boolean res = false;
    boolean actual = list.isEmpty();
    assertEquals(res, actual);
}
```

*И в-третьих*, На мой взгляд, этот паттерн усложняет написание некоторых тестов. Например:

```
@Test
public void testCicleNext() {
    assertEquals(8, list.next().getId());
    assertEquals(7, list.next().getId());
    assertEquals(9, list.next().getId());
    assertFalse(list.hasNext());
    assertEquals(8, list.next().getId());
    assertTrue(list.hasNext());
}
```

Тут перед каждым ассертом придется создавать по 2 переменные. В результате тест разрастется до огромных размеров и читать его по-моему станет только тяжелее.

Comment: Вы про это http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ArrangeActAssert ?

Comment: @Vartlok, да, об этом

Answer (score 3):

В любом паттерне всегда можно найти такой случай, когда он выглядит нелепо. Я думаю, что Вы как раз и привели такой пример.

Классические обоснования паттерна 3А (да, так он пишется - три А) следующие:

- код разделяется на три логические части.
- функция тестирования четко тестирует две вещи, без побочных эффектов.

разберем первый тест:

```
assertEquals(3, list.size());
```

Здесь не всегда понятно, есть ли у функции size побочные эффекты (да, в этом случае это звучит глупо, но в общем случае - нет). И допустим этот тест захотелось закомментировать временно. А код в тесте ниже может неявно зависеть от побочных эффектов. И все, прилетели... (да, в этом конкретном тесте одна строка, но кто его знает)

> Во-вторых, что делать вот с таким тестом?

```
@Test
public void testIsEmpty() {
    assertTrue(!list.isEmpty());
}
```

А этот тест просто нужно правильно написать. Где то так

```
@Test
public void testListIsNotEmpty() {
    bool is_empty = list.isEmpty();
    assertFalse(is_empty);
}
```

Видите разницу? нет переменных типа `res`, значение которых не понятно. Также, если список не должен быть пуст, то это и нужно тестить, а не противоположность (видите, я даже имя теста поменял).

А теперь посмотрим на последний тест

```
@Test
public void testCicleNext() {
    assertEquals(8, list.next().getId());
    assertEquals(7, list.next().getId());
    assertEquals(9, list.next().getId());
    assertFalse(list.hasNext());
    assertEquals(8, list.next().getId());
    assertTrue(list.hasNext());
}
```

В этом примере next модифицирует исходный объект. И если одну строку закомментировать, то все, тест может порушиться.

Этот тест кстати можно переписать через цикл и сразу он стает красивее и проще. И не нужно создавать кучу переменных.

```
@Test
public void testCicleNext() {
    int test_data[] = {8,7,9,8};
    for (int i = 0; i < test_data.length(); i++) {
      int expect = test_data[i];
      int actual = list.next().getId();
      bool has_next = list.hasNext();
      assertEquals(expect, actual);
      assertTrue(has_next );
    }
}
```

Теперь, если нужно добавить ещё 5-6 тестируемых значений, то это очень просто.

Мое личное мнение. Внутри тестируемых функций (то есть, assertEquals и подобных) не должно быть сложных конструкций. На то они и **юнит** тесты, что  бы тестировать **минимальную единицу** кода.  И если size еще как то допустим, то методы, которые модифицируют объект - нет.

Если у меня возникает ситуация, что мне нужно продебажить функцию/метод, который я тестирую, то это первый звонок, что функция сложная и ее нужно разбить или переписать.  Если тест стает очень большим (а Вы на это жалуетесь), значит тест написан неверно - его нужно либо разбить на два поменьше, либо написать правильно (я, к примеру в плюсах люблю для этого делать макросы:) ).

Но в любом случае не нужно страдать паттернами головного мозга и применять их везде и всюду. Нужно применять их по надобности.

*я давно не писал на Java, поэтому в коде могут быть мелкие опечатки.*

Answer (score 0):

[Arrange-Act-Assert](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ArrangeActAssert) - это шаблон для форматирования Unit тестов. Обозначающий разделения теста на 3 части

1. Arrange - все необходимые подготовки и входные данные
2. Act - собственно вызов того метода который вы тестируете
3. Assert - проверки, что метод делает то что надо

В ваших пример со списком должно быть что-то такое:

```
@Test
public void testAdditionAndSize() {
    // Arrange - подготавливаем данные для теста
    SomeClass obj = new SomeClass;

    // Act - выполняем метод add
    list.add(obj);

    // Assert - проверяем, что объект добавился
    assertEquals(1, list.size());
    assertEquals(obj, list.get(1));
    // другие тесты проверяющие что добавился правильный объект, что он не изменился и т.д.
}
```